# jpod library not working outside eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface, jna, freetype

If I run project from eclipse - it's ok. If I run project as runnable jar exception thrown:

```
.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at de.intarsys.pdf.platform.cwt.font.freetype.FreetypeFontFactory.getLib
rary(Unknown Source)
        at de.intarsys.pdf.platform.cwt.font.freetype.FreetypeFontFactory.create
PlatformFont(Unknown Source)
        at de.intarsys.pdf.platform.cwt.rendering.CSPlatformDevice.textSetFont(U
nknown Source)
        at de.intarsys.pdf.content.CSDeviceBasedInterpreter.render_Tf(Unknown So
urce)
        at de.intarsys.pdf.content.CSInterpreter.process(Unknown Source)
        at de.intarsys.pdf.content.CSInterpreter.process(Unknown Source)
        at de.intarsys.pdf.content.CSDeviceBasedInterpreter.process(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at RenderDoc.renderPage(RenderDoc.java:75)
        at RenderDoc.renderPages(RenderDoc.java:97)
        at RenderDoc.run(RenderDoc.java:139)
        at RenderDoc.main(RenderDoc.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: no native interface available
        at de.intarsys.nativec.api.NativeInterface.set(Unknown Source)
        at de.intarsys.nativec.api.NativeInterface.get(Unknown Source)
        at de.intarsys.cwt.freetype.nativec._FTNI.init(Unknown Source)
        at de.intarsys.cwt.freetype.nativec._FTNI.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at de.intarsys.cwt.freetype.Freetype.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        ... 11 more
```

My system windows7 64 bit, java 8 64 bit. I think problem, that freetype.dll not seen outside eclipse. I found it inside jar (jpod dependencies). How I can correctly include this dll in packaging jar, and why it works from eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is from May but in case anyone still has this problem ...
The Freetype dll is automatically extracted from the jar file into your temp folder and loaded from there. But the message you get means that the JNA bridge cannot be initialized. That's a problem with your classpath. You need jna.jar and the other jpod dependencies in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

JNA can automatically extract shared libraries if they are found within [a predefined set of locations](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.0.0/javadoc/index.html).

Most likely the value of `java.classpath` is different when running under Eclipse than running standalone (print the value on startup to see).  You need to ensure that your classpath is equivalent in both situations, and that the shared library is included in your final deployment under a path that JNA can access and ultimately use (it does no good to include the shared library in a jar if JNA cannot extract it to a location from which it can be loaded by the system).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, that the native library could not be loaded on my windows system.

**Cause:**

I have used the WebSphere Java 8 Runtime, which could not correctly extract the native libraries.

**Solution:**

Use of official Oracle JRE 8.